# Pecl oci8 failed install after upgrade to PHP5.6

Tags: php, centos, pecl

I am trying to upgrade all my servers to php 5.6 currently and that has gone great except for installing  oci8. It was working great with php55 and I have even pulled down a brand new vagrantbox with centos to test it out and make sure it's a completely clean install.

When I try to run the install I get the following errors.

```
# pecl install oci8
downloading oci8-2.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.0.8.tgz (190,854 bytes)
.........................................done: 190,854 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8
running: /var/tmp/oci8/configure --with-oci8
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 5.6.0, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... no
checking size of long int... 8
checking checking if we're on a 64-bit platform... yes
configure: WARNING: OCI8 extension: ORACLE_HOME is not set, looking for default Oracle Instant Client instead
checking Oracle Instant Client directory... /usr/lib/oracle/11.2/client64/lib
checking Oracle Instant Client SDK header directory... /usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64
checking Oracle Instant Client library version compatibility... 11.1
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /bin/sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1966080
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for ar... ar
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if cc static flag -static works... no
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating config.h
config.status: executing libtool commands
running: make
/bin/sh /var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c -o oci8.lo
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/var/tmp/oci8 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8/include -I/var/tmp/pear-build-rootMIYqiX/oci8-2.0.8/main -I/var/tmp/oci8 -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/include/oracle/11.2/client64 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/oci8.o
In file included from /var/tmp/oci8/oci8.c:46:
/var/tmp/oci8/php_oci8_int.h:48:29: error: oci8_dtrace_gen.h: No such file or directory
make: *** [oci8.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

So looks to be an issue with DTRACE. I looked around and found this was a change made in php56 and to enable it you need to run...

```
export PHP_DTRACE=yes
```

After running `pecl install oci8` again I now get this.

```
# pecl install oci8
downloading oci8-2.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download oci8-2.0.8.tgz (190,854 bytes)
.........................................done: 190,854 bytes
11 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
Please provide the path to the ORACLE_HOME directory. Use 'instantclient,/path/to/instant/client/lib' if you're compiling with Oracle Instant Client [autodetect] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootIwscfS/oci8-2.0.8
running: /var/tmp/oci8/configure --with-oci8
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for Oracle Database OCI8 support... yes, shared
checking PHP version... 5.6.0, ok
checking OCI8 DTrace support... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking sys/sdt.h usability... no
checking sys/sdt.h presence... no
checking for sys/sdt.h... no
configure: error: Cannot find sys/sdt.h which is required for DTrace support
ERROR: `/var/tmp/oci8/configure --with-oci8' failed
```

This has been tried with the oracle 11.2 instant client and the 12.1 instant client. Both with the exact same results.

EDIT:
Here is all the information I have found when trying to trouble shoot this.
http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.extensions.php -- Change in PHP56
http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.dtrace.php -- Enabling DTRACE
http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2011/downgrading-a-pecl-module -- Rolling back the version for pecl
http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8 -- list of oci8 versions

Comment: Are you compiling PHP as well or do you use a repo for that? You might be able to `yum install php-pecl-oci8` and avoid the hassle of compiling PECL

Comment: @Machavity I installed php56 from the remi repository so it shouldn't be an issue. I believe I did try yum install php-pecl-oci8 but ran into another issue. I will bring up a fresh vagrant box though and add any details from installing it that way to this post.

Comment: @Machavity I did try it with php-pecl-oci8 with the same results. It appears that running that does not actually install the oracle instant client for you.

Comment: That sounds right. I wouldn't expect PECL to contain the (likely licensed) client, only the PHP software necessary to use it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found a solution to this although I don't like it and hope that someone has a better one. Rolling back to the last stable version everything seems to work fine running..

```
pecl install -f oci8-1.4.10
```

Comment: Would have loved to select a different answer but looks like we don't have much interest in this question. However the above will get you off the ground and running.

Answer (score 29):

I fix this problem in my CENTOS 6.6 and php 5.6.8 in these two ways:

1. If you need DTRACE:

   - yum install systemtap-sdt-devel
   - export PHP_DTRACE=yes
   - pecl install oci8
2. if you don't like DTRACE:

   - Download the oci8 tar ball and extract the files
   - modify the file 'php_oci8_int.h', change the 48th line

      `#include "oci8_dtrace_gen.h"` to `#undef HAVE_OCI8_DTRACE`
   - phpize
   - ./configure --with-oci8=
   - make
   - make install

Comment: for CentOS7 and PHP7.3 only way 2. worked.
extra explanation:
$ ./configure --with-oci8=<path to instant client>
e.g.:
$ ./configure --with-oci8=/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib

Comment: sorry, should be $ ./configure --with-oci8=instantclient,/usr/lib/oracle/18.5/client64/lib